# Having all mail for my domain controlled by a Gmail account

Tags: gmail, google-workspace, google-apps-email

I have `exampledomain.com` (which I control) and a `examplegmail@gmail.com` email address. I would like to merge my email, so I just have one account - all inbound mail to `exampledomain.com` would go to `examplegmail@gmail.com`.

My reasoning - my `exampledomain.com` isn't that "professional" a name, so (bizarre as it may sound) I actually want `examplegmail@gmail.com` to be my neutral persona (although want to keep all incoming mail coming into `examplegmail@gmail.com` for legacy purposes and labeled as such!)

1. Is this possible? (I'm not sure of the most elegant way to achieve this - do I need to setup Google Apps for `exampledomain.com` and grant access to this from `examplegmail@gmail.com` - before I start messing around with MX records, does granting from Apps to Gmail work? My concern is that I'd need to check the `exampledomain.com` Apps account's Spam box frequently, as this would be separate from my `examplegmail@gmail.com` Spam box).
2. Can I just copy across my saved `exampledomain.com` emails (IMAP4) to `examplegmail@gmail.com` using Thunderbird, or is there a faster direct web-to-web method instead of it all going via my PC?
3. If I ever wanted to send "from something@exampledomain.com" (using the examplegmail@gmail.com account) would this be possible?

I'm running myself in circles - if anyone can help, I'd be really grateful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two options, the one that gives you the most control, setting up a google apps account, or the one that is easiest to setup, using your host's pop3 in gmail.

I personally use the first option. I've currently got Google Apps setup on my own domain, [dkuntz2.com](http://dkuntz2.com). The gmail account for my apps (don@dkuntz2.com) is set to forward all mail to my gmail account and archive everything (so I still have it if I need it). This is in settings -> forwarding and pop3.

On my gmail account, I set it up so that I can access the dkuntz2 account (it's in settings -> accounts, just type in the email address, that one will get a message saying confirm, you click the link and bingo, you've got send access). This way, everything is controlled by a central gmail account, but I can still send as dkuntz2. I've also done this with two other domains, and it works soundly so far.

In my own settings I've also told it to respond as the address that's mailed to (so if I get a dkuntz2 email it sends it as dkuntz2, same for the other addresses), and each address also has it's own signature (more fun settings).

Comment: That sounds interesting, thanks!
Just to clarify, you'd just set up "don" as a catch-all email within Google Apps?
When addresses are forwarded to your Gmail, do they show as being from "don@dkuntz2.com" or the original sender?
I think http://www.mydigitallife.info/2008/11/24/how-to-disable-and-deactivate-spam-filter-protection-in-gmail-or-google-mail/ answers the spam question.
Sorry for all the questions, but it's a scary thing to test...

Comment: Well, I did, simply so I had a catch-all, but that's purely optional. In my main gmail, I've created a filter for each address that tags anything that's sent to that address as being to that address (so you have to set it up first, but after it's done it's good). The filters are simply if to don@dkuntz2.com, mark as dkuntz2, otherwise don't mark it as anything. Technically it'll show up as to the address it's sent, however you would have to view the headers to see that, otherwise it just looks like a standard piece of mail.

Comment: Thanks - I've taken the plunge and moved across - massively more simple than I feared!

Answer (score 0):

A while ago I wrote about this. The short answer is, it is possible. Things are especially easy if your other account is a Google Apps account. You can get all your mails at your other account to be forwarded to your Gmail account. And the best thing is, it is also easy to send mail from your other account using the Gmail web interface.

You can start by reading my [blog post](http://phunehehe.isgreat.org/2009/manage-multiple-email-accounts-with-gmail/), or going to [Gmail's "Accounts and Import" settings](https://mail.google.com/mail/#settings/accounts) and try the configurations.

Answer (score 0):

Google just released [Email-delegation](http://gmailblog.blogspot.com/2010/12/email-delegation-granting-access-to.html) for all email accounts, not just Google Apps, so you might be able to use that for sending and receiving from one account on behalf of the other.

Comment: Thanks. Having looked at the link, I can now see that delegation just provide access, but doesn't merge the mailboxes, so not exactly what I want. Thanks anyway!